# Custom UITableViewCell with UIImageView giving wrong size for this last one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm struggling with a "small" issue. I have a UITableView who displays images loaded from a remote server. For each one of these images I have their width and height, so I use those values to calculate the aspect ratio.

I have a height constraint on the Image View where I'm displaying the image, so when I have the aspect ratio, I change this constraint before returning the cell on the delegate's method.

In order to calculate the aspect ratio I use the width of the Image View, and this one is calculated using constraints on IB. Like this.

[image]

The width I'm getting when I'm dequeuing the cell is the same set at IB. So my aspect ratio is wrong for a moment because is not using the proper width. Also, for a brief moment, the cell is using the height constraint set on IB before changing to the height constraint set on code. This is the method I use.

```
- (void)updateConstraint
{
  // get method has been created by me on a NSDictionary extension
  NSNumber *heightNumber = [self.articleItem.data get:kHeightKey];
  NSNumber *widthNumber = [self.articleItem.data get:kWidthKey];
  self.imageAspectRatio = 16/9;

  if (heightNumber != nil && widthNumber != nil) {
    self.imageWidth = widthNumber.floatValue;
    self.imageHeight = heightNumber.floatValue;
    self.imageAspectRatio = self.imageWidth / self.imageHeight;
  }

  self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = self.articleImageView.frame.size.width / self.imageAspectRatio;
}
```

For cell height I'm returning `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

I don't know if I'm doing all the calculation correctly and in the proper place (obviously not). Anyone can show the wight way? Thank you so much.

Comment: After updating your constraint, you should call `layoutIfNeeded`. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, and with that what I'm getting is the cell with the wrong height for a moment, before is updated and displayed in the proper height.

Answer (score 1):

Trust me, there's absolutely nothing "small" about this issue. If there were, then I'm probably just an idiot who thinks that can code. (Oh wait - [maybe I am?](https://www.raywenderlich.com/165042/rwdevcon-2017-inspiration-talk-im-idiot-richard-turton) Anyway :)

I don't have all the answers for you. What I know is that, I believe, I have what you want "more or less" working for me, so I'll try to help you out with the ideas that I've gathered either from the official documentation or from my many hours searching for answers on Stack Overflow itself.

[image]

First, some assumptions:

1. You know the width of all your `UITableViewCell`'s `UIImageView`s, from what I can gather looking at the picture you posted. Either they're "full bleed" (i.e. you use the full width of the screen, like in my screenshot) or you use some margins - the important thing is that you know the width, and what you dynamically want to change is the height.
2. You mention this briefly, but again, it doesn't hurt to make sure. **You're not waiting to fetch the image to set the height constraint.** Instead, by the time you return from the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you've already updated your constraint. This is very important since AutoLayout likes to know the height of the cell before the user sees it.

Now, I believe your code looks OK. I'm sure you've looked at it through the debugger, done the math yourself, found out your height constraint's value is fine, but still, you can't get it to show properly as you want it to. You don't mention whether you're getting AutoLayout errors in your logs, so it's hard to tell exactly where your problem is, but I can point you towards the strategy that helped me a lot:

1. When you learn of the height of a new `UIImage` you want to set, don't change your constraint directly. Instead, call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`.
2. Override `updateConstraints()`, **and call `super.updateConstraints()` last**. [This is heavily emphasized in the official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ModifyingConstraints.html):

> Always call the superclasses implementation as the last step of your
>   updateConstraints method’s implementation.

3. Before you call `super.updateConstraints()`, update your height constraint for the new `UIImage`. Why is this important? Besides this being the recommended way if you read the documentation, I believe doing this allows us to avoid the famous `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` AutoLayout errors which happen because the system will add constraints to fix the height of the `UITableViewCell`, and if we don't update our height constraint first, AutoLayout will be forced to break some constraint.

A couple of extra notes:

1. Try playing around with your tableView's `estimatedRowHeight` property; set that to zero and see what happens. Or give it a more accurate value.
2. Don't use **`heightForRowAtIndexPath()`** or related methods, they're incredibly slow, and you'll mess up your self-sizing cells. I recommend trying them out to see if playing with those values sheds some light to your AutoLayout, woes, but not for a product's release.
3. Don't be disheartened. No matter what you might think, ***this is hard stuff***.

I believe I can help you further if you provide us with more information (say screenshots, AutoLayout errors, etc.)

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the long and detailed answer. About the assumptions, that's where i have the first problem and is that I don't have the correct width of the image. If I log the width of the imageView at the moment I need it to calculate and apply the aspect ratio of the image to the imageView, what I've got is the current width of the cell in IB. I mean, instead of giving me the proper width after calculating it using the constraints I set, is giving me a placeholder value. And that's killing me :(

Comment: You don't need to have the correct width of the image - you have width of your `UIImageView`; if you use `contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` and set the correct height constraint, the OS will handle the rest. If your width is the width of the cell, isn't that value correct? You only need to figure out the width and height of the `UIImageView`, not of your `UIImage`.

Comment: My mistake, what I was trying to say is that the width of the ´UIImageView´ is the incorrect one, not the image. The width of the ´UIImageView´at the moment I'm using it with the image aspect ratio is a value set by IB, not the constraints I set, so my calculated height is wrong.

Comment: I see. Have you tried hooking up those constraints you've set in IB as `@IBAction` so you can reference them directly in code and modify them?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing after calculating the proper height of the ´UIImageView´, change its height constraint referenced as ´IBOutlet´. But the value of the constraints also have the wrong value at first, using the default set by IB at the moment. For example, I set a constraint to value 0 if is running on compact width (iPhone) and 70 if is running on regular width (iPad). But the first time I dequeue the cell on iPad, this constraint value is 0, because that's what I'm seeing on IB.

Comment: Seems like this is your real issue :)

I'm out of ideas for this, actually. I've done all of this in code, since it avoids me unwanted changes made by IB/Xcode as time progresses, but this is like asking you to shoot a fly with a cannon.

Are the constraints set correctly on the iPhone simulator? Have you tried on a different simulator / OS version? Or on a different device?

Comment: I test always with device (I don't trust the simulator ¬¬). I tried also to set all with programatically constraints, but I found it way more complicated.

Comment: Any updates on your issue? Please post an answer if you find a valid solution for you.

Comment: I'll do. But right now, the only solution I found implies to set a fixed width instead of using the one coming from IB, so my height is correctly calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps reloading the tableView when the images are retrieved from the remote server would help. `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: This is not an answer. Please use the comments for follow-up questions.

Comment: The expected behaviour should be that the image view inside the cell should have the same size as the image. I can achieve this because I have the Width and Height of the image before loading it. So I can calculate the aspect ratio of the image and use this same aspect ratio on the image view

Comment: So, you have width and height (so you have aspect ratio). You set the correct constants, then you call `layoutIfNeeded()`, right?

Comment: Also, are you using the method `heightForRowAtIndexPath` from the delegate or the `rowHeight` property?

Comment: Yes, is set to UITableViewAutomaticDimension, so it gets the height after calculating constraints

Comment: But the constraint is set after a `layoutIfNeeded` and then a  `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` for each row (or a `reloadData` at the end of setting all constraints).